# MVC Controller to API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC Controller already written. Now, I have to code the same action methods of the MVC Controller to a **new API Controller**.

What all changes would be needed to put a method in the API Controller?

For Eg. MVC Controller Code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EAuthorize(xyz)]
    public ActionResult Trans()
    {
        var user = (User)WebSession.CurrentUser;
        var mTrans = mTransLMgr.InitializeMTrans(user.currentSelectedEntity.Value);
        mTransLMgr.AccNum = TController.GetAccountNumberBasedOnPrivilage(x,y);            
        return View(mTransLMgr);
    }
```

If I have to implement the same method in an API Controller, what are the changes I will have to implement. The methods should return JSON.

Comment: Please review the question. Have edited it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert a MVC controller to an API Controller. Both types devires from different base classes. In ASP.NET MVC a controller have to derive from `Controller` class, while in ASP.NET WEB API a controller the base class is a `ApiController`. In both cases, you inherit from a custom controller base, but this one must inherit from the original base controller provided by the plataform.

In ASP.NET WEB API, the result format is provided by `content-type` provided on the [`http header`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). So, your client application must provided the `application/json` on the `content-type` attribute and the ASP.NET WEB API will serialize in this format for you. For Sample:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var user = (User)WebSession.CurrentUser;

    var mTrans = mTransLMgr.InitializeMTrans(user.currentSelectedEntity.Value);        
    mTransLMgr.AccNum = TController.GetAccountNumberBasedOnPrivilage(x,y);            

    // return ok with the model serialized on the response body
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatus.Ok, mTransLMgr);    
}
```

I am not sure what you have on the `WebSession.CurrentUser`, but if you use a key on the `HttpContext.Session[key]` you cannot do this because ASP.Net is stateless and you do not have sessions.

For the `EAuthorize` you have to implement authentication in the http header. You can do this using the Basic Authentication, which is the default behaviour of the Rest applications. I strongly recommend you to read the article [Basic Authentication in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) and see in details how to do it.

Your question is too broad and maybe other users can close it. I think it is good you try to implement and ask for some help posting your code of what you've tried.

Comment: I guess I explained my question in a wrong way. With convert I meant implementing an API Controller. I have an MVC Controller already in place but now I need to implement an API Controller with the  same methods as in the MVC. I was curious on how can I implement that. What changes would happen? I would like to know how can I implement that taking an example on any basic method.

Comment: I see, Well, edit your question and post a sample code of what you have tried or your mvc controller, and we can cooperate with you :)

Comment: @RenuR I've edited my anwser, I hope it help.